# How to format JSENCODE on a javascript variable retrieved from a query?

Tags: javascript, custom-button, docusign

I have a javascript button that retrieves a few variables from a query:

```
var o = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Opportunity_Contact__r.FirstName, Opportunity_Contact__r.LastName, Opportunity_Contact_Email__c from Opportunity where id = '{!Advance__c.ApplicationId__c}'");

var OC = o.getArray("records");

var FN = OC[0].Opportunity_Contact__r.FirstName;
var LN = OC[0].Opportunity_Contact__r.LastName;
var EM = OC[0].Opportunity_Contact_Email__c;

--------------------
CRL='Email~'+EM+';Role~Signer 1;FirstName~'+FN+';LastName~'+LN;

window.location.href ="{!URLFOR('/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope',null,[SourceID=Advance__c.Id])}&DSEID=0&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;
```

EM is used in a URL and has the potential for special characters so I wanted to encapsulate in `{!JSENCODE()}`. It does not work on the javascript variable itself, coming back with the field does not exist, but it also doesn't work when setting the variable. Its not recognizing `Opportunity_Contact_Email__c` as a field even though that does exist in salesforce. Where would be the proper place to put this so the URL can handle potential special characters?

Answer (score 0):

```
CRL=encodeURIComponent('Email~'+EM+';Role~Signer 1;FirstName~'+FN+';LastName~'+LN);
```

this worked